# Would you choose Selenium instead of Testbench (Vaadin)? Planning the automation tool before starting the new project

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am about to start a new web project and one of my team members suggests to use Vaadin solution instead of Selenium.

**If you have to pick up a web app automation tool, what will you choose between Selenium and Testbench?** If possible, please argument your choice by comparing.

Except the fact that some components are license ba$ed [Freemium], I found that the internet resources (considering Github  w/ loads of Selenium libs and Stalkoverflow) are reduced for Testbench compared to Selenium. I've also noticed that Testbench is Selenium based.

Except the Vaadin's official site, there is no other comparison to be found, so I encourage you to share your thoughts on this. Your experience will help the automation engineers (instead of a long term try) to take a better decision that fits their specific needs.

What other automation tools are you using / recommending?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, selenium is an open source tool as compared to vaadin testbench.
Second, Vaadin testbench is solely created to test the Vaadin application but with the help of selenium you can deal with general web applications.
You can check the below link where in the first line itself they have written about that.
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/testbench/testbench-overview.html
Third, There are many frameworks out there for selenium as compared to testbench. So long time maintenance would be difficult in vaadin testbench.

So bottom line is if you have to test the vaadin application then go with the vaadin testbench. otherwise without a second thought, go with the selenium :)

If you want then I can tell you more about this.